# Endless loop with controlled exit

Tags: java, loops, batch-processing, exit

I need an Batch-Program with endless loop. In this loop he is doing something and then wait's x seconds. Now the Problem, how can I stop the loop from outside of the Program? One Option is to read a File and break if s.o. wrotes "STOP" inside, but how it is with performance if I always open and close the file?

Isn't it possible to start a second thread inside the same runtime, e.g. to set an Boolean 'run' to false or something else?
Here is my code with "stop-file".

```
 Integer endurance = args[3] != null ? new Integer(args[3]) : new Integer(System.getProperty("endurance"));
 BufferedReader stop = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(args[4] != null ? args[4] : System.getProperty("StopFile")));
        while (!stop.readLine().toUpperCase().equals("STOP"))
        {
            doSomething(args);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(endurance);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                System.exit(12);
            }
            stop.close();
            stop = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(args[4] != null ? args[4] : System.getProperty("StopFile")));
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have done like this previously in Android.  I started the logic in child thread and sent interrupt signal from Parent thread.  Sample code somewhat like below.

```
   class TestInterruptingThread1 extends Thread
{
    public void run()
    {
        try
        {
            //doBatchLogicInLoop();
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e)
        {
            throw new RuntimeException("Thread interrupted..." + e);
        }

    }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        TestInterruptingThread1 t1 = new TestInterruptingThread1();
        t1.start();
        boolean stopFlag = false;
        try
        {
            while (stopFlag == false)
            {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                //stopFlag = readFromFile();
            }
            t1.interrupt();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("Exception handled " + e);
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can think of at the moment is to use a [Socket](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/) and have another separate process sending actions to your client. In other words, you will have a Server-Client connection. Try [this tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_networking.htm)

Answer (score 0):

A simpler way than reading a file, you may check for the existence of a file with `exists()`.

```
File stopFile = new File(System.getProperty("StopFile"));

while (!stopFile.exists()){
```

Of course you would probably want to delete this file after your loop.

```
stopFile.delete();
```

Answer (score 0):

I also propose Sockets like Monoteq proposed. If you don't want to use Sockets I would not read the file and scan for content, but just test for existence. This should improve performance.

```
File f;
while((f= new File(args[4] != null ? args[4] : System.getProperty("StopFile"))).exists()) {
    doSomething();
}
f.delete();
```

Still not the most beautiful solution, but better than reading the content of the file.